# Angular material mat-checkbox does not highlight when element if focused via tab key

Tags: angular, angular-material

As the title suggests, mat-checkbox does not show the usual circular highlight around it on focus when I navigate to the element via the tab key. Not sure whats causing the behaviour.

Here are the details:
"@angular/cdk": "11.2.9"
"@angular/material": "11.2.9"
Angular CLI: 12.1.4
Node: 14.16.1
Package Manager: npm 6.14.12

I have tried upgrading cdk and material to latest versions, still it won't work.

Thank you

Comment: Use the console to see what's wrong, if you don't have a style that overrides it

Comment: @marcant0 yes found the issue, there was css property override it, had to dig deep into it, thanks